# R - how to load each file from folder

Tags: r

I have a folder and that contains a lot of R files, that files are functions actually. What I need is to create code in another project in R which will load each file in that folder and load this functions in to the environment.

I know that better option is to create a R package from this functions but it can´t be done for several reasons in my case.

What is the simplest way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What exactly are the several reasons you can't make a package? Have you tried anything at all yet? Where exactly are you getting stuck? Presumably you just want to run `source()` on each of those files? Did you try something like `Map(list.files("folder/.*R"), source)`?

Comment: Oops, got my parameters mixed up, it should be more like `Map(source, list.files(path="myfolder", pattern="R$"))`

Comment: Hi, Im still getting this error `Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'active_payment_promises.R': No such file or directory` I dotn´t know what is wrong, it says that directory doesn´t exsists but active_payment_promises is actually my function there and it loaded it

Comment: Try passing `full.names = TRUE` to `list.files()`